# Get Values from an Object

Tags: java, sqlite, object, hashmap, onlongclicklistener

I tried a few solutions on stack overflow but they seem to not work for me.

I use the following onlongclicklistener

```
Object j = (Quote) MainActivity.this.adapter.getItem(position);
```

The following is my object J

Now I would like to get the value of ticker into a string

How do I go about this. Do I need a Hashmap ?

```
String valueofticker = j.toString(ticker); // How to do this ?
```

[image]

Comment: Make `j` of type `Quote`, then call methods on it like `j.getTickerValue()` or what have you.

Comment: Apologies but would you be able to provide an example ?

Comment: Without access to your `Quote` class, I have no way of knowing what methods it has.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/6EQf25fc This is my portfolio class. My quote class has just a bunch of declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the items inside the adapter is a list of Quote objects, then you could do this:

```
class Quote {
     private String ticker;

     // create getter and setter methods here for all
     // the variables in the Quote class.
}
```

Get Quote using this:

```
Quote qObj = (Quote) MainActivity.this.adapter.getItem(position);
```

Get the ticker value like this:

```
String tickerValue = qObj.getTicker();
// the same will apply for all other variables of the class Quote.
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I know this will sound very dumb but my issue is I am not sure how to fetch the ticker value from the object.  See my adapter here where I am not sure how to define the getTicker()  http://pastebin.com/GrbQLKES

Comment: cant the ticker string be a property inside the quotes class? Why is it outside the quotes class ??

Comment: It could be but I have just made all functions declaration outside. I am a very beginner coder. So was unsure that needed to be done initially. See the Quote class here - http://pastebin.com/J4bAtpzy

Comment: may be you could try qObj.tickerText ???  that way you could get the text  assigned to tickerText

Comment: No doesn't seem to work. I think I would probably need a hashmap ?

Comment: inside the Quote class, where you have the variables declared, can u create getter and setter methods? then use the setter method to set the value and getter method to get the value. if it doesnt work then may be you could try the hashmap though i am not sure why its needed.

Comment: Ahhh - Figured it out. You were right. All I needed to do was String Ticker = qObj.ticker;  . Thank you so much for taking the time to keep answering. I thought you would give up after your first attempt.

Comment: @Sam glad it worked for you and that you figured it out.. !! Happy coding :)